# read 9th column from text file and replace 11th column to the same file

Tags: linux, awk, sed, linux-mint

I want to read 9th column of text file with '~' delimiter and need to retrieve data from for the corresponding 11th column which resides in a table. that data i need to replace in 11th column of the file which is having NULL values currently.

How to achieve this in unix.

```
col1~col2~col3~col4~col5~col6~col7~col8~col9~col10~col11~col12~col13

data1~data2~data3~data4~data5~data6~data7~data8~data9~data10~~data12~data13
```

in the data data11 is null . so i want to take the corresponding value for data9 and replace the data11.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want only to copy column 9 to column 11 this can be done with script like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="~"; OFS="~"}{$11=$9; print}' <filename>
```

If the first file have only one line you can do something like:

```
awk -v val=$(awk -F\~ '{print $9}' <filename b>) 'BEGIN {FS="~"; OFS="~"}{$11=val; print}' <filename a>
```

Comment: otherwise if i want to replace the data from col2 in b file to col11 in a file. how can i achieve this.

Comment: @LakshminarayanaReddy, please clarify this explicitly in question. Its very unclear. I will add something which you can use but w/o precise question this may or may not work. Is it file `a` only one line or you want to to replace from multiline file?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I fully understand. Would this come close?

```
awk -F~ '!$11 {$11 = $9}1' OFS="~" file
col1~col2~col3~col4~col5~col6~col7~col8~col9~col10~col11~col12~col13
data1~data2~data3~data4~data5~data6~data7~data8~data9~data10~data9~data12~data13
```